# Convert MariaDB SQL into Laravel Query

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-query-builder, mariadb-10.1

This is the working SQL in MariaDB:

```
SELECT * FROM ticket_categories
WHERE cat_name LIKE '%test%'
AND 
   ( cat_parent_id = 236 
     OR cat_id = 236
     OR cat_parent_id
     IN (SELECT cat_id FROM ticket_categories Where cat_parent_id = 236)
   )
```

What I have in Laravel Query so far:

```
$categoryList->where('ticket_categories.cat_name','like','%'.$request->input('name_filter').'%')
             ->where(function($query) use($request) {
                     query->where('ticket_categories.cat_parent_id', '=', $request->input('departments_filter'));
                     $query->orWhere('ticket_categories.cat_id','=', $request->input('departments_filter'));
                     $query->orWhereIn('ticket_categories.cat_parent_id', function($query1) use ($request) {
                            $query1->select('cat_id')
                            ->from(with(new TicketCategory)->getTable())
                                  ->where('cat_parent_id', '=', $request->input('departments_filter'));
                          });
                     });
```

My code is now working but you can you can look for people's answer that is much cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would rewrite your raw MariaDB query as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM ticket_categories tc1
LEFT JOIN ticket_categories tc2
    ON tc1.cat_parent_id = tc2.cat_id AND
       tc2.cat_parent_id = 236
WHERE
    tc1.cat_name LIKE '%test%' AND
    (
        tc1.cat_parent_id = 236 OR
        tc1.cat_id = 236 OR
        tc2.cat_id IS NOT NULL
    );
```

This would correspond to the following Laravel code:

```
$results = DB::table('ticket_categories tc1')
    ->leftJoin('ticket_categories tc2', function($join) {
        $join->on('tc1.cat_parent_id', '=', 'tc2.cat_i ');
        $join->on('tc2.cat_parent_id', '=', 236);
    ->where('tc1.cat_name', 'like', '%test%')
    ->where(function($q) {
        $q->where('tc1.cat_parent_id', 236)
        ->orWhere('tc1.cat_id', 236)
        ->OrWhereNotNull('tc2.cat_id')
    })
    ->get();
```

Note that this answer assumes that a given category would have only one parent.  If not, then my left join approach could generate duplicates.  A workaround would be to use an `EXISTS` query in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'tc2.cat_id IS NOT NULL)' at line 11.

Comment: Sorry, there was an `OR` missing (keep in mind that I can't test my code...only you can do that).

Comment: your raw sql is working. My structure in database is Department->Category->Subcategory and your code is much cleaner. I will try to implement the Query Builder approach and tag this as the correct answer.